# SQL -Select date of the first day of the week of any given date, group by year week, with first day of the week based on user locale

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb, dayofweek

Using mariadb, I want to create some report data from daily data entries stored in a table.
For the report, I need to group the data based on the given yearweek, and I need to return the first day of the week.

For this, I need to define twice what the actual first day of the user is, and I would like to do this dynamically based on the user's locale - alternatively, I would want to use Monday as the default.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_yearweek.asp
States:
firstdayofweek

Optional. Specifies what day the week starts on. Can be one of the following:

```
0 - First day of week is Sunday
1 - First day of week is Monday and the first week has more than 3 days
2 - First day of week is Sunday
3 - First day of week is Monday and the first week has more than 3 days
4 - First day of week is Sunday and the first week has more than 3 days
5 - First day of week is Monday
6 - First day of week is Sunday and the first week has more than 3 days
7 - First day of week is Monday
```

--

Not sure what really the difference is between:
First day of week is Monday and the first week has more than 3 days
and 5 - First day of week is Monday.

I just want the default as expected in the USA, for example - so I would assume that is the value 5?

Comment: *Not sure what really the difference is between: First day of week is Monday and the first week has more than 3 days and 5 - First day of week is Monday.* This means that if the most first week of the year (which is 86% partial because its first days are in previous year) has more/not more than 3 day, then this partial week will or will not be counted, or it will be counted anyway.

Comment: This may help you as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: Your table is missing if the week number is 0 or 1 based: https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/functions/yearweek.php

Comment: You probably mean my query. I am ware of YEARWEEK( date_value, [ mode ] ) as stated in the link. The problem is, there are several modes available, and I am unsure about the difference between mode 5 and 1, for instance. Further, I would like to do two since - group by the right weeks, and return the right first day of the week. Further, it would be nice if there was a way to adjust the "week mode" as a default setup to the US standard, it seems Sunday is the default.